# How to check angular material 2 mat-list-option is checked or not?

Tags: angular-material2

I want to use a mat-list-option to checked or unchecked a group of mat-list-options but i can't check that the mat-list-option is checked or not with $event.

Answer (score 2):

You could also assign a template reference to the `mat-list-option` and check if it is `selected`

> TemplateRef: `#option` then use **option.selected**

```
<mat-selection-list #shoes>
  <mat-list-option #option *ngFor="let shoe of typesOfShoes">
    {{shoe}} <div style="font-weight:bold">{{option.selected}}</div>
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gl4wqq?embed=1&file=app/list-selection-example.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-list-option (click)="selectGroup($event.toElement.getAttribute('ng-reflect-state'))">
</mat-list-option>
```

ng-reflect-state keep an string value that show mat-list-option status, the value may be "checked" or "unchecked".